# Convert NSInteger into NSString

Tags: interview-questions, objective-c, formatting, integer

This is my sample code to convert a integer into string.

Is it very costly to do the multiple loops of *[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:..]*?

I.e should I just use appendString and get the NSString in reverse order and then do one for loop to reverse this "reverse string".

Is there any other faster/more elegant way?

```
NSString * intToString(NSInteger numberToConvert)
{
    BOOL isNegative = (numberToConvert < 0);
    if (isNegative)
    {
        numberToConvert = -1*numberToConvert;
    }

    NSMutableString *convertedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    while(numberToConvert != 0)
    {
        convertedString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%@",numberToConvert%10,convertedString];
        numberToConvert = numberToConvert/10;
    }

    if (isNegative)
    {
        convertedString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",convertedString];
    }

    return convertedString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Umm… this is a complicated solution that makes no sense.  [Why not keep it simple](//stackoverflow.com/q/384089/1157100)?

```
NSString *intToString(NSInteger numberToConvert)
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", numberToConvert];
}
```

If, on the other hand, the exercise is to implement your own solution from scratch, then I would consider it cheating to use `NSMutableString stringWithFormat:`.  Either way, I would consider your solution to be a failed response in an interview situation.

Comment: What would your response be in an interview question, where I need to do it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
NSString *intToString(NSInteger numberToConvert) {

    return [@(numberToConvert) stringValue];
}
```

Using NSNumber's stringValue method.

written without literals

```
return [[NSNumber numberWithInteger(numberToConvert)] stringValue];
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question. Which has been known to occur before...

Comment: It creates a temp NSNumber object for conversion, not good for me.